Qwidget elements not showing in secondary window
I am trying to open a QWidget when close even in QMainWindow is triggered. The QWidget need to stay open until the for loop gets completed. The QWidget is showing up, but the elements in the widget is kept being invisible. Please help.
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PySide6.QtGui import QFont
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

class Loader(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('ManagerBee - Loader') 
        self.resize(250, 130)
        self.h1 = QFont()
        self.h1.setPointSize(9)
        self.h1.setBold(True)


        self.itemVL_1 = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.loaderText = QLabel("Auto Backup is in progress.<br/>System will close automatically.")
        self.loaderText.setFont(self.h1)
        self.loaderText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.itemVL_1.addWidget(self.loaderText)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My Main Window")
        self.closeEvent = self.close_event

    def close_event(self,event):
        self.closingLoader = Loader()
        self.closingLoader.setWindowFlags(self.closingLoader.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.closingLoader.show()
        upload.uploadFile('db.sqlite3',str(self.userData[0]))
        self.closingLoader.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()

Here I add the upload code.
import ftplib
import os
import shutil
import datetime
from alertbox import AlertBox
import db

FTP_HOST = "ftp.domain.com"
FTP_USER = "user@domain.com"
FTP_PASS = "iCQL^7;eIpbD"


def uploadFile(filename, index):
     try:
          ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
     except:
          alert_box = AlertBox("Unable to Connect Network", "No internet connection. Auto backup failed.")
          alert_box.exec()
          return
     ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
     os.getcwd()
     shutil.copy(filename,index+'_'+filename) 
     local_file = index+'_'+filename

     with open(local_file, "rb") as file:
          ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {local_file}", file)

     os.remove(index+'_'+filename)

     ftp.quit()

def downloadFile(filename):
     try:
          ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
     except:
          alert_box = AlertBox("Unable to Connect Network", "No internet connection. Restoration Failed.")
          alert_box.exec()
          return
     ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
     with open(filename, "wb") as file:
      #use FTP's RETR command to downlohad the file
          ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {filename}", file.write)

     db.db.close()
     os.getcwd()
     shutil.copy("db.sqlite3", str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')) + "_" + "db.sqlite3")
     os.remove("db.sqlite3")
   
     os.rename(filename, "db.sqlite3")

     db.db = db.QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
     db.db.setDatabaseName('db.sqlite3')
     if not db.db.open():
          db.exit()
     db.query = db.QtSql.QSqlQuery()

     ftp.quit()

This is what I am getting as an output now:

This is what the secondary widget should look like.


The for loop is blocking, preventing the event loop to properly process all its events, including drawing the UI. Please clarify what exactly happens in that for loop, as there may be different solutions depending on many aspects.

Thank you @musicamante for the reply. There is an upload script running in place of the loop. I just want to have a message popup for the user to inform them of background work going on. Please suggest. Thank you!!

don't use long running code in GUIs - like your for-loop - because it may block main event loop. It may need to run code in separate thread. OR you may use (probably) QTimer to execute some (small) code periodically without blocking code. In some GUIs you may run update() to execute main event loop once - so it has time to update elements in wIndow.

@furas update() doesn't process the event loop queue, it schedules an update. repaint() may work in some cases, but I'm not sure it eventually triggers further repaints() in related widgets (siblings, parents or children). In any case, it's not appropriate for this case, as its repaint may be based on a state that would be invalid for the events in the current queue, including layout requests.

@Sayan "upload script running" is too broad. Please [edit] your post and clarify what happens there exactly.

Thanks to everybody for your suggestions. @musicamante I have added two images. The first one is what I am getting right now and the second one what the secondary widget should look like. Please suggest.

@Sayan You already explained the result you got, we did not ask for screenshots. You must explain what actually happens instead of that for loop. Please provide a proper [mre].

@musicamante I have edited the code. Please have a look when you have some time. Thank you!!
